# How can declare multiple image url in android

Tags: android, imageview

How can declared dynamically multiple images URL and i want to display selected one image not display all  images.Images retrieved in Server.

I tried this code only one image is retrieved from server. I need to how declare and retrieve multiple images and this same code can declare images.

The coding is as follow,..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

class Image_Async extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Bitmap,Bitmap>
{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap  bmp=    null;
        try {
            URL url =
 new URL("http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs42/i/2009/132/7/2/DIWA_boy_animation_by_LunarRain27.jpg");
            try {

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Anybody give your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'm not sure what you are asking for exactly.

If you want to be able to cache images (download many and display one at a time) use Universal Image Loader
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

If you are just looking for a way to download multiple images, then instead of decoding the bitmap, open the input stream and write to a file.

```
try {
    final File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "imagename goes here");
    final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            // this is the input stream from your url connection
            while ((read = inputstream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);

            output.flush();
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} finally {
    inputstream.close();
}
```

as you are not going to want to have that many images in RAM for no reason. (but maybe you do have a reason?

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

anyways, you run one of the above in a loop for as many images as you have, on a background thread, have it notify you when it is done. example

```
class EZAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Bitmap>>
{

    private AsyncTaskListener listener;
    private List<String> urlList;

    public EZAsyncTask(List<String> urlList, AsyncTaskListener listener)
    {
        super();
        this.urlList = urlList;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        List<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        for (String url : urlList)
        {
            bitmapList.add(getBitmapFromURL(url));
        }
        return bitmapList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> bitmapList)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmapList);
        listener.onCompletion(bitmapList);
    }

    public interface AsyncTaskListener
    {
        public void onCompletion(List<Bitmap> bitmapList);
    }

}
```

and use it like this

```
urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
urlList.add("http://images.fastcompany.com/upload/Simple.jpg");

EZAsyncTask ezTask = new EZAsyncTask(urlList, new AsyncTaskListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(List<Bitmap> bitmapList)
{
    // TODO handle response
}
});
ezTask.execute();
```

Anyways there is a lot there. Try to understand it all if you can, it will help greatly in the long run ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of URL string and Bitmap..

And process them one by one adding the result if the InputStream to the Bitmap array on each URL..

**The problem..**

Lets say you have a lot of URL with BitMaps it may result to OutOfMemoryException